# How to import custom modules in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, module

I am trying to use one of the custom modules I have built and put it in another module

custom modules:

my-test.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { MyTestComponent } from './my-test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyTestComponent    
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,    
  ],  
  exports: [ MyTestComponent]
})
export class MyTestModule { }
```

Another module that I need to pull in

my-parent.module.ts

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import { MyParentComponent } from './my-parent.component';
import { MyTestModule } from '../my-test/my-test.module';

@NgModule({
    'imports': [
        CommonModule,
        MyTestModule        
    ],
    'declarations': [
        MyParentComponent
    ],    
    'exports': [
        MyParentComponent
    ]   
})

export class MyParentModule {}
```

my-parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, Injectable, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { MyTestComponent } from '../my-test/my-test.component'

@Component({
    'selector': 'my-parent',
    'template': `
       test
    `
})

@Injectable()

export class MyParentComponent implements OnInit {    
    public myTestComponent: MyTestComponent;
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
       console.log(this.myTestComponent)  <----show undefined here.
    }    
}
```

I am not sure how to import the my-test component into my-parent component. 
What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

**Update**

Slightly change my codes above to fit my case. It initial a `MytestComponent` in the beginning and `this.myTestComponent` shows undefined.

Comment: you want to use my-test.module.ts in side  my-parent.module.ts ?

Comment: @mohammad yes that's my intention

Comment: i did the same structure that you did but the only problem that the component should have initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- in my-parent.component.html add `<test component selector> </ test component selector #test>`

2- in the parent ts file add :

```
@ViewChild('test') test: MyTestComponent;
```

then you will be able to access all the methods and parameters in MyTestComponent

Comment: It shows {} is not assignable error when I add ={}. Also, why should you assign value to a component? +1

Comment: In JavaScript and type script , parameters are default to undefined. However, in some situations it might be useful to set a different default value. This is where default parameters can help. 

so it looks like this for the compiler 
 public myTest: MyTestComponent= 'undefined';

Comment: please if you found my answer is stable for you , close the question  by marking the answer as the right answer .

Comment: I am still having trouble. I can't assign {} to a component. It says {} is not assignable to type MyTestComponent

Comment: man let us under stand what you want to do because exporting is not working like that ill help you until we solve the problem

Comment: Your template doesn't even contain a reference to test component.  Also, if you want to get a reference to it, use the `@ViewChild()` decorator e.g. `@ViewChild() public myTest: MyTestComponent;`

Comment: @mohammad Thanks for you help. I figured it out by myself. It was not related to what I posted here. :D